# How can I revert an entire subdirectory on my branch to be what it is on main?

Tags: git, github

I have a branch in pull request. However, I have committed some changes that I don't want, so it will show changes like so:

```
package.json
yarn.lock
packages/
  some-package/
    a.ts
    b.ts
    styles/
      c.css
```

I want to revert the *entire* `packages/**` directory to what it was before my PR was opened

How would this be done?

Comment: I would check out the entire directory from an earlier commit where its state is correct, then add and commit (and push).

Comment: Side note: you asked for and got a "revert to" answer; just remember when you get around to using `git revert` that it's not a "revert to" (doesn't turn things back to how they were), but rather an "undo specified commit" (basically reverse-apply the changes from some commit). Mercurial had a better verb here, `backout`; Git authors unfortunately chose the verb `revert`, which implies the wrong thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sh
git restore --source=main ./packages
git add packages
git commit -m "Remove accidentally committed packages"
# Optionally git push
```